# Implementing a listener for multiple event listeners of different classes (activity, fragment, etc), in Android

Tags: java, android, listener

MyApplication application class has a listener that notifies an event listener (MainActivity - fragment activity) when `fetchUpdates` method is called.

**Setup (showing only relavant part):**

(1) MyApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   OnFetchStartListener mCallbackFetchStart = null;

   public void setOnFetchStartListener(Activity activity) {
       try {
           mCallbackFetchStart = (OnFetchStartListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFetchStartListener");
       }
   }

   public interface OnFetchStartListener {
       public void onFetchStartListener();
   }

   public synchronized void fetchUpdates() {
       // Informing listeners on fetchUpdates() start
       if (mCallbackFetchStart != null) {
           mCallbackFetchStart.onFetchStartListener();
       }
       String[] mURLs = getURLs();
       new DownloadDataAsyncTask().execute(mURLs[0], mURLs[1]);
   }
}
```

(2) MainActivity - FragmentActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
      MyApplication.OnFetchStartListener

   static MyApplication myApp;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      myApp.setOnFetchStartListener(this);
      super.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   public void onFetchStartListener() {
      //Some stuff
   }
}
```

**Question**

How can I setup the listener in the application class to notify multiple event listeners? The event listeners may be of different classes, not just FragmentActivities.

I can create different listeners in the application class to notify different event listeners (a listener in the application class for each event listener) when `fetchUpdates` is called, but this doesn't strike me as very efficient.

**About me**

I just started programming. So detailed explanations are much appreciated.

**Progress**

[Rciovati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321354/rciovati) Suggested using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). This solution might work, but will have to introduce a new (third-party) library in to the project.

I'm still looking for a solution without having to use a third-party library.

Comment: May be you are looking for [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) ?

Comment: I guess you should take a look at this library: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @AdilSoomro No, `BroadcastReceivers` wont do the job.
@rciovati EventBus looks promising. Is there an example or sample project available?